# Can TogglerBar be used as multiple CheckBox in Mathematica?

Tags: checkbox, wolfram-mathematica, togglebutton

Would it be possible to have a **TogglerBar instead of the 2 Check Box** to show or not the different Shapes.

With Green & Red written in each Button of the TogglerBar ?

```
Manipulate[
Graphics[{If[thePink, {Pink, Disk[{5, 5}, 3]}], 
If[theGreen, {Green, Disk[{15, 2}, 1]}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}], {{thePink, True, 
Style["Pink", Black, Bold, 12]}, {True, False}}, {{theGreen, True, 
Style["Green", Black, Bold, 12]}, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

The actual Manipulate object I am trying to adjust can be found there : http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/COG.html
The purpose being to replace the CheckBox by a nice TogglerBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   {White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},  (* For Mma 7 compatibility*) 
   If[MemberQ[color, "Red"],   {Pink, Disk[{5, 5}, r]}],
   If[MemberQ[color, "Green"], {Green, Disk[{4, 2}, r]}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}],
 {{r, 1, "Radius"}, 1, 5, 1, ControlType -> Setter},
 {{color, "Red", "Color"}, {"Red", "Green"}, ControlType -> TogglerBar}, 
LabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Answering your comment, I think your notebook could benefit from a template like this one:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  {
   {White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},(* For Mma 7 compatibility*) 
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Circle"], {Red,   Circle   [{5, 5}, r]}],
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Square"], {Blue,  Rectangle[{5, 5}, {r, r}]}],
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Other"],  {Black, Line     [Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}],
  },
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}
 ], 
  (* Controls follow *)
  {{r, 1,  Style["Radius", Black, Bold, 12]}, 1, 5, 1, ControlType     -> Slider
                                                     , ControlPlacement-> Top
  },  
  Control@{{whatToDisplay, True, Style["What", Black, Bold, 12]}, 
           {"Circle", "Square", "Other"}, 
           ControlType      -> TogglerBar,
           Appearance       -> "Vertical",
           ControlPlacement -> Left
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: @Belisarius, I want to be able to select both. I would actually implement that to show or hide different visual component of my analysis. Please let me know if you would have an alternative to the one below. Thank You.

Comment: @ Belisarius, I have upload my notebook to the below link. If you have a minute, do you think I have hope to apply this to all my If statement to hvae a nice single bar instead of all the CheckBox ? Run all the Notebook should be all that is necessary to display the Object. thank You once again for you attention. http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/COG.html

Comment: @Belisarius, this is just perfect. I hope my codes were not to ugly to your expert eye ;)

Comment: @Belisarius. Could we  adjust the the font inside ? If you think it is worth another post for the interest of the forum, I shall ask the question.

Comment: @500 Your code is OK. Sometimes you forget to use the functional constructs, but that is normal while you're learning. BTW ... what is a `COG`?

Comment: @Belisarius, Center of Gravity,

Comment: @500 Oh my! And I was a physicist!

Comment: @Belisarius,  We can hardly reckon familiar things out of the context we are usually expecting them in ;)

Comment: @500 That reminds me of a Groucho Marx's joke that went something like "I met my wife at the hotel, but I didn't recognize her because she was wearing a wedding dress"

Comment: @Belisarius, that is really funny !

Comment: @500 I've read in your profile `Ph.D. Student in Cognition ` and I thought `COG` was related to cognition. Really funny!

Comment: belisarius, the first block gives me errors on mma7.  "Null is not a Graphics primitive or directive." etc...

Comment: @Mr. Edited, but can't test it. Check now ... or upgrade! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[myObject], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}], {{myObject, {},""}, {{Pink, 
     Disk[{5, 5}, 3]} -> 
    Style["Pink", Black, Bold, 12], {Green, Disk[{15, 2}, 1]} -> 
    Style["Green", Black, Bold, 12]}}, ControlType -> TogglerBar]
```

Comment: Thank You !, any way to hide the "u" ?

Comment: @500 "u" was displaying as the label for the variable; the label is an option for any of the dynamic variables. I changed "u" to myObject and gave it an empty string: "", for the label option. The empty string will not display although you can put more descriptive names instead. As an aside note that `Show` isn't essential in this case as `Graphics` could use the plot range. But `Show` might come in useful for future extensions of this example.

Comment: Thank You ! You will find in the edited question the source to see the "real problem" if you care/have time.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Manipulate[
Graphics[{#} & /@ x,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}],
{{x, {}, "Colour"},
{{Pink, Disk[{5, 5}, 3]} \[Rule] "Pink",
{Green, Disk[{15, 2}, 1]} \[Rule] "Green"},
ControlType -> TogglerBar}]
```

it's ugly and inelegant, though! Dynamic manipulation is not my favourite use of Mathematica, so this is sort of trial and error for me too...

EDIT: Slightly less ugly now...
EDIT2: Added a label

Comment: Thank You. However I must say I don`t understand how it works yet and for I need to implement it with a quite complex Manipulate. I will try to Edit my question to show the problem :) I leave it unanswered yet to see if others have ideas !

Comment: @500 no problem. note that I've added a label now (I saw you were asking how to do it). maybe give more details about what you don't understand (or what your real problem is).

Comment: You will find my notebook with only the relevant Manipulate Object left open. Do you think I have hope to apply this to all my If statement to have a nice single bar instead of all the CheckBox ? Command A Shift Enter should be all that is necessary to see the object ! Many thanks for your attention ! http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/COG.html   Many thanks for any help you can provide !

Comment: @500 should not be a problem, but it is late here and I'll quit. if nobody's done it by tomorrow, I will :)