# Adjust TogglerBar button size in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, togglebutton

Is it possible to adjust the size/font of the TogglerBar, so that they are all equally large in case of different name size.

The example below is the  solution proposed by Belisarius for :  ["Can TogglerBar be used as multiple CheckBox in Mathematica ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299215/can-togglerbar-be-used-as-multiple-checkbox-in-mathematica)

I would like each Button to be equally sized.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[
{
{White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},(*For Mma 7 compatibility*)
If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "I am a Circle"],
{Red, Circle[{5, 5}, r]}],
If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "and I am a very nice Square"], {Blue,
Rectangle[{5, 5}, {r, r}]}],
If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Other"], {Black,
 Line[Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}]
},
PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}
],
{{r, 1, Style["Radius", Black, Bold, 12]}, 1, 5, 1,
ControlType -> Slider,
ControlPlacement -> Top},  
Control@{{whatToDisplay, True,
Style["What", Black, Bold, 12]}, {"I am a Circle",
"and I am a very nice Square", "Other"},
ControlType -> TogglerBar,
Appearance -> "Horizontal",
ControlPlacement -> Top}]
```

[image]

**EDIT** : It is trully ugly in the code (if we can still call that a code) but looks good on display.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica 8 introduced `Overlay` which allows multiple expressions to be easily overlaid atop each other.  Coupled with `Invisible` (from v6), we have all the necessary ingredients to easily synchronize all of the button sizes without resorting to counting spaces or pixels.  The following code illustrates their use, with the relevant parts emphasized:

`DynamicModule[{options, allLabels, size, pad}
, options =
    { "I am a Circle" -> {Red, Circle[{5, 5}, size]}
    , "and I am a very nice Square" -> {Blue, Rectangle[{5, 5}, {size, size}]}
    , "Other" -> {Black, Line[Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}
    }
; allLabels = options[[All, 1]]
; pad[label_] :=
    Overlay[Append[Invisible /@ allLabels, label], Alignment -> Center]
; Manipulate[
    Graphics[what /. options /. size -> r, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}]
  , {{r, 1, "Radius"}, 1, 5, 1}
  , {{what, {}, "What"}, # -> pad[#] & /@ allLabels, TogglerBar}
  ]
]`

[image: Manipulate result]

The definition:

```
pad[label_] :=
  Overlay[Append[Invisible /@ allLabels, label], Alignment -> Center]
```

defines a function that stacks all of the labels invisibly atop one another, and then puts the desired label visibly on top of that.  The result is the desired label with enough whitespace on either side to accommodate any of the other labels.

The `Manipulate` statement uses `pad` to create the labels for the `TogglerBar`:
`{{what, {}, "What"}, # -> pad[#] & /@ allLabels, TogglerBar}`

Note that the labels are specified in the form `value -> label` to allow the values to retain their original form without the `Overlay` and `Invisible` specifiers added by `pad`.

Comment: +1 automatically padding everything correctly without counting!

Answer (score 5):

This is a way, although not completely satisfactory because the Panel length is not automatically calculated. Let's call it a first approach ...

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},(*For Mma 7 compatibility*)
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "I am a Circle"], {Red, Circle[{5, 5}, r]}], 
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "and I am a very nice Square"],
                                               {Blue, Rectangle[{5, 5}, {r, r}]}], 
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Other"], {Black, Line[Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}],
  {{r, 1, Style["Radius", Black, Bold, 12]}, 1, 5, 1, ControlType -> Slider, 
                                                 ControlPlacement -> Top}, 


 Control@{{whatToDisplay, True, Style["What", Black, Bold, 12]}, 
           (# ->  Panel[#, ImageSize -> 150, FrameMargins -> 0, 
                           Background -> White, 
                           Alignment -> Center]) & /@ 
           {"I am a Circle",  "and I am a very nice Square", "Other"}, 
           ControlType -> TogglerBar,
           Appearance -> "Horizontal", 
           ControlPlacement -> Top}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

here you have a better approach, with automatic size calculation:

```
(* get the Image Size first*)
ley = {"I am a Circle", "and I am  Square", "Other"};
sZ = Max[Dimensions[ImageData[Rasterize[#][[1]]]][[2]] & /@ ley];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[
 {{White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},(*For Mma 7 compatibility*)
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "I am a Circle"], 
                                     {Red, Circle[{5, 5}, r]}], 
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "and I am a very nice Square"],
                                     {Blue, Rectangle[{5, 5}, {r, r}]}], 
   If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Other"], 
                                     {Black, Line[Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}],

 (*Controls Follow *)

 {{r, 1, Style["Radius", Black, Bold, 12]}, 1, 5, 1, 
    ControlType      -> Slider, 
    ControlPlacement -> Top }, 

  Control@{{whatToDisplay, True, Style["What", Black, Bold, 12]},
    (# -> Panel[#, ImageSize    -> sZ, 
                   FrameMargins -> 0, 
                   Background   -> White, 
                   Alignment    -> Center]) & /@ ley,
     ControlType      -> TogglerBar, 
     Appearance       -> "Horizontal", 
     ControlPlacement -> Top}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Mathematica may have an option somewhere to do this, but I don't know it. So, here is a proposed solution:
First, this pads a string left and right so that it is of length `n`:

```
  Clear[strpad];
strpad[str_String, n_] := Module[
{strlength, exc, excr},
    strlength = StringLength@str;
    exc = Floor[(n - strlength)/2];
    excr = n - strlength - exc;
    StringJoin[
        Table[" ", {i, exc}],
        str,
        StringJoin[Table[" ", {i, excr}]]]]
```

Then, modify your program so that either you use these padded strings or add a `Rule[#, strpad[#, 30]] & /@` immediately before `{"I am a Circle", "and I am a very nice Square", "Other"}`, so that your code becomes

```
 Manipulate[
   Graphics[{{White, Circle[{5, 5}, r]},(*For Mma 7 compatibility*)
 If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "I am a Circle"], {Red, 
 Circle[{5, 5}, r]}], 
  If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "and I am a very nice Square"], {Blue, 
 Rectangle[{5, 5}, {r, r}]}], 
  If[MemberQ[whatToDisplay, "Other"], {Black, 
 Line[Tuples[{3, 4}, 2]]}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 10}}], {{r, 1, 
  Style["Radius", Black, Bold, 12]}, 1, 5, 1, ControlType -> Slider, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top}, 
Control@{{whatToDisplay, True, Style["What", Black, Bold, 12]}, 
  Rule[#, strpad[#, 30]] & /@ {"I am a Circle", "and I am a very nice Square", "Other"},ControlType -> TogglerBar, Appearance -> "Horizontal", 
 ControlPlacement -> Top}]
```

Comment: @acl but that will not result in equal boxes if the letters are not monospaced

Comment: @acl, Belisarius, Thank You both,  you will see in the edit the horror I could come up with myself !

Comment: @belisarius it tacks spaces on to the left and right of the string. I am not sure what the importance of monospaced or proportional fonts is, since the spaces won't change size. No doubt I am missing something. In any case, using Panel is probably conceptually cleaner.

Comment: @acl: what belisarius means is that in some fonts, "llll" will be _thinner_ (for want of a better word), compared to "XXX" (as you can see in this comment). So tagging on extra spaces to the latter might not help to bring them level. In monospaced font, each character has the same width (e.g., `llll` vs `XXX`), and in that case your method will work.

Comment: @yoda Thanks for the explanation. I was trying to come up with something clearer than my previous comment to no avail

Comment: @yoda thanks. I know what monospaced and proportionally-spaced fonts are :) I just don't see how adding 5 spaces on each side can leave the  text different distances from either edge, monospaced or not. but I guess you guys know better :) [or are we talking about columns? then yes...]

Comment: @yoda, @belisarius hmm, what am i saying... of course you're right!